# Totalcross - A versão 3.30 é suportada até que versão do Android

Tags: totalcross

Gerei um apk com a versão 3.30, instalei no Android 7.1 e ao executar o aplicativo, renderiza somente uma tela preta. Até o Android 6... funciona corretamente.

Comment: Qual o build do TotalCross? Qualquer coisa, você pode ver a informação dentros dos `sources`, `totalcross.sys.Settings`, propriedade `buildNumber` (fica na linha 45)

Comment: Confirmado o funcionamento eu tenho no Android 7.0 =/ Estou procurando um aparelho 7.1 para confirmar

Comment: No momento, estou sem Android 7.1 perto de mim. Não vejo porque não funcionaria... Estou usando a build `3235` para os testes

Comment: Tambem utilizo o build 3235. Não sei se seria relevante, mas notei também que ao gerar o apk, o ant esta lançando essa mensagem no console (não lembro de ver ela ao gerar o apk nas versões anteriores do Totalcross):

Could not find 'google-services.json', thus Firebase will be ignored further on

Comment: No caso esse aviso de não achar o `google-services.json` não está relacionado. Isso é só avisando que não vai conseguir usar o serviço de Push disponibilizado pelo Firebase. Vou testar no emulador do 7.1. Enquanto isso, qual o aparelho que apresentou isso?

Comment: É um ZenPhone 5, porem o android não é o oficial.

Comment: Não tenho esse aparelho para validar. Não li nada que impediria o TotalCross de rodar num Android 7.1 normal. Por baixo dos panos, usamos o OpenGLE para renderizar os componentes na interface, talvez nessa imagem baixada eles tenham alterado algo nesse sentido?